# Cross-thread set control

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to set the thread you are using a control created on another thread.

Controls that were created on a different thread: `PictureBox PBox`, `SplitContainer _sc`

```
enter code here
class Class1
{
    public Class1(SplitContainer _sc,PictureBox PBox)
    {
        SetPanel(_sc,PBox);
    }


    delegate void SetPanelDele(SplitContainer _sc, PictureBox pb);
    void SetPanel(SplitContainer _sc, PictureBox pb)
    {
        if (pb.InvokeRequired && _sc.InvokeRequired)
        {
            pb.Invoke(new SetPanelDele(SetPanel), new object[] { _sc, pb });
        }
        else
        {
            pb.Parent = _sc.Panel2; // here
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: You should probably be checking `this.InvokeRequired`, not `pb.InvokeRequired`

Answer (score 2):

Please note that if `pb.InvokeRequired != _sc.InvokeRequired` then you have a **serious problem** there, both controls must be *valid* on UI thread.

Answer to your question then it's **no, you can't** use a control created in another thread unless you make sure handle has not been created on that thread.

**In short** (let me simplify little bit): all controls must be created and accessed from UI thread. No exceptions.

**Little bit longer**: it's possible to create an instance from any thread but *handle* must be created within UI thread. It means that sc and pb may be created in two different threads and then merged together into UI within UI thread but you have to be sure to do not call any method or set any property that will cause handle to be created.

It *may* be done but it's **incredibly fragile**. What you can do is to provide a factory method you will invoke on appropriate thread:

```
static void AddControl(Control control, Func<Control> factory)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.BeginInvoke(
            new Action<Control, Func<Control>>(AddToControls), control, factory);
    }
    else
    {
        control.Controls.Add(factory());
    }
}
```

It will then be used like this:

```
// I'm in another non UI thread...
AddControl(splitContainer, () =>
{
    // Just an example...
    return new PictureBox
    {
        Size = new Size(40, 40),
        Image = LoadImageFromFile()
    };
});
```

Note that factory method will capture variables and you may need some synchronization if you access shared resources with calling thread. I used `BeginInvoke()` instead of `Invoke()` to do not block calling thread, things are easier because in WinForms we don't need to call `EndInvoke()`.

---

Side note unrelated to your question, you should stick on a naming convention, now you have `_sc` (underscore prefixed for function argument), `PBox` (title case for function argument), `pb` (all lower case - or camel case - for function argument). It's little bit confusing, usually arguments and local variables are unprefixed camel case identifiers.

Comment: thank you 
but I can not use it to ask for examples.

Comment: `AddToControls(_sc, )`